What is "__common_interrupt: 1.52 No irq handler for vector"?
I checked all answers around this, and it seems these cover installation and boot problems. Here I experience no problem whatsoever, except that the notification has been bringing this up in a rather regular fashion, about once per hour. And the number is always 1.52 or 1.53.
A complete line could look like this:
Jul 18 16:17:28 mybox kernel: [79594.945289] __common_interrupt: 1.52 No irq handler for vector

What is this, and how can I get rid of it, please?
6.5.0-41-generic #41~22.04.2-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Jun  3 11:32:55 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

It is a normal laptop, and I am not aware of any specific installs.
Lenovo T400, standard, except of SSD 1TB retrofitted.
These messages started some weeks ago, precisely on 10th of June.

As written there is no way to offer any help. What is the version of Ubuntu you are using? What kernel are you using? What have you installed that might be causing this? These are just some of the details that you need to add to your question. Please use edit and not answer in comments.
